# nginx tolower config var

Tags: url-rewriting, nginx, memcached

Is there a way to strtolower() an nginx env var? For example I want to do something like:

set $memcached_key strtolower($request_uri);

I want to do this because when storing values into memcache, I want to make the key the lowercase.

Also, I just want to make the part of the URI before '?' lowercase, not the entire URI.

Ex:
/some/ThING/soemthing.php?key=VaLuE -> /some/thing/soemthing.php?key=VaLuE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing I have found that seems to work is [using the perl module](http://nginx.2469901.n2.nabble.com/rewrite-to-lowercase-td4492672.html) to create a function that returns the value you want.